# Can you put form elements in a DOS batch file?

Tags: forms, command-line, batch-file, dos, exe

Can you put form elements in a batch file?  I was curious when I saw it in [Word 5.5 for DOS](http://download.microsoft.com/download/word97win/Wd55_be/97/WIN98/EN-US/Wd55_ben.exe).  I can't find out how to do it, but I know NOTHING about all that junk in an executable file for DOS.  Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Please provide a better description on exactly what you're looking for.  Leaving it at just "form element" implies that a person looking for the answer posted here understands what a "form element" is.  Either a description of the interaction, or simply sample input and sample output would work.

Comment: I mean like a text area, combo box, or text box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask for free text in a batch file use:

```
SET /P UserName=What is your UserName?
```

This puts the user's response in an environment variable named UserName, which can be accessed with **%UserName%**

like this:

```
ECHO Hello, %UserName%.  Welcome to planet Earth!
```

Comment: +1 - I guess this is actually a better interpretation of the word "form element", since he's probably talking about HTML forms.  I was thinking "menu".

Answer (score 0):

You can put any executable command in a batch file, hence you can do anything in a batch file.  If you see anything terribly fancy (like windowing), you probably are looking at a third party program, rather than a command built into the command processor itself.

Off the top of my head, the closest thing to a form (something that you can select items from) that I can think of is the `CHOICE` command.  To find out how to use it, type this at a command prompt:

```
CHOICE /?
```

Here's the description...

> This tool allows users to select one item from a list
>   of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

Here are some syntax examples...

```
CHOICE /?
CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /CS /D y
CHOICE /C ab /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
CHOICE /C ab /N /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
```

And here's a full example:

```
CHOICE /C:ABCDN /N /T:10 /D:N /M:"Format drive A:, B:, C:, D: or None?"
REM Note that ERRORLEVEL handlers must be in decreasing order...
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET DRIVE=None
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET DRIVE=drive D:
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET DRIVE=drive C:
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET DRIVE=drive B:
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET DRIVE=drive A:
ECHO You chose to format %DRIVE%
```